# Perform Undo and Destroy Childs from ContextMenu Editor Mode Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

it can't Perform **Undo** when call a method via ContextMenu for Instantiate gameObject In Editor, And second From a ContextMenu call a method for **Destroy** all Childs , not any action or get Error in unity .

```
for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)   
 { DestroyImmediate(transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all with what you are doing you won't destroy all child objects anyway.

After you `DestroyImmediate` the first child object the `childCount` will be reduced by one and at the same time all remaining children move one index up so your next `i` is skipping an object ;)

In general you would probably rather go through the [`Undo`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Undo.html) class and use [`Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate.html) like e.g.

```
// This simply iterates exactly transform.childCount times
for(var i = transform.childCount; i > 0; i--)
{
    // This always destroyes the first child
    // Since after destroying all childs move one index up
    // this works to get and destroy them all one by one
    // And this now logs an undo/redo action for this destroy
    Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(transform.GetChild(0));
}
```

and for adding objects use accordingly [`Undo.RegisterCreatedObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Undo.RegisterCreatedObjectUndo.html) like

```
var obj = new GameObject();
Undo.RegisterCreatedObject(obj);
```

---

Note: Since the `Undo` class is in the `UnityEditor` namespace it will be completely stripped of in a build.

Therefore make sure it is

- Only in editor scripts placed in a folder called `Editor` or an assembly that is only compiled for the editor
- or it is always wrapped by preprocessors like

  ```
  #if UNITY_EDITOR
  Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(obj);
  #endif
  ```